# using randomize() without time.h in C

Tags: c, random, time.h

I was able to run code that uses the randomize function without including the time.h library. is it automatically included with some other libraries i might have already included in my code? Below is a list of the libraries I included:

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <io.h>
```

Comment: one of heater line may have included time.h with in that

Comment: Are you using the TurboC compiler?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein It's like this:

`randomize();`
`random(300);`

@0A0D I'm using TurboC++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very very specific to the version and implementation of your library. The standard doesn't force any header to include `time.h` <sup>1</sup> so you cannot rely on that.

In your case, it could be that one of `dos.h`, `io.h`, `conio.h` for example has included `time.h` (or any other of the headers there for all it's worth).

---

<sup>1</sup> At least not the ones there and not likely in your seemingly ancient library. C11 says `threads.h` should include `time.h`

Comment: Would this line in `dos.h` explain it:

`void        _Cdecl _dos_gettime( struct dostime_t *__timep );`

Comment: @yonatan, I cannot find any documentation on `randomize()`, so I can't really tell. However it seems like your calls (i.e. `randomize()` and `random(300)`) do _not_ use time functions at all. Why do you expect `time.h` to be included? You need to find out where `randomize` is defined in your non standard platform. `stdlib.h` is a good guess.

Comment: As `randomize()` makes the initial value of `random()` random based on the current time and the compiler documentation therefore states it requires `time.h`.

Comment: Since `randomize()` is not taking any parameter, then it is calling `time.h` related functions _itself_. This means that in the source file implementing the function `randomize()`, `time.h` is included. Once that source file has been compiled by whoever wrote the library that comes with turbo C, `randomize()` would work correctly all by itself. You wouldn't need to include a header file for it.

Comment: From your terminology, I think I understand where the problem is. You see, when you write `#include <time.h>`, you are **not** including a _library_, you are merely making the interface to the library visible to you. The library itself is linked at a later phase after the compilation and by the linker. So if you don't _use_ the time functions yourself, you don't need to include its header files. However, since the time functions are in the standard library, they _will_ get linked with your program whether you like it or not.

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/333964/912144), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1945846/912144) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file) for example.

Answer (score 1):

What does `<compiler with high warning level> yourcode.c` say? My guess would be:

- either one of the non-standard DOS-specific headers (`conio.h`, `dos.h`, `io.h`, ...) includes it,
- or there's no declaration at all, i. e. it's not included, in which case your compiler silently and implicitly assumes a function signature (specifically, it assumes a return value of `int` and whatever type of argument you call it with for the first time).

Note that the latter case is **wrong,** and you should pay attention **not to do it** (since it may lead your program invoking undefined behavior). Always compile with all warnings enabled so you can track down such an error.

Comment: @0A0D Please elaborate, what do you mean by that? I've looked at that link and there's no `time()` in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: I mean that on a non-standard platform, such as the ticalc website I linked to, randomize() is a function in stdlib.

Answer (score 1):

When C compiler can't find a prototype to a function it assumes it is a function that returns int. It also prints a warning function if you didn't change the default settings.

So. In your case perhaps time.h was included, but be aware that it can cause a lot of problems if it wasn't.