# How we call .c using .h files?

Tags: linker, connection

I really do not get the relationship between .c files and .h files. If i call .h files from a program(modelica), does this .h file call .c files directly? Or how is it work? Thanks.

Comment: It clearly explains here the .h file
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945846/c-what-should-go-into-an-h-file

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6264249/1362568). Applies equally to C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "calling a .c (or .h) file" - your code will allways call the object code in the compiled files. The header file (.h) will provide you with a prototype of what is in there, so you can use functions in a precompiled library by just referencing the .h file with an `#include`.

This allows you to have a single shared binary (.so, .dll,  .dylib, ...) and use the header files to link to them.