# How do I use and enum in multiple files c++

Tags: c++

I want to use an enum in multiple different files but I don't know how to. For instance, if in one cpp file I have something like `enum Numbers  {  one = 1, two = 2  }`

how can I use this enum in a different file?

Comment: You would want to put this enum definition in [_a header file_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757350/what-should-go-in-my-header-file-in-c/25757789).

Comment: (I'd flesh out more details in an answer, but I suspect this question is more suited as a duplicate of my link.  But maybe I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

You can put the enum definition in a header file. For example:

```
//numbers.h

#pragma once
enum Numbers { one = 1, two = 2 };
```

And then you can use these enums in any source file, provided you include the header:

```
//source.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "numbers.h"

void printNumber(Numbers num)
{
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

And this way, you can have access to the enum across any source file.