# Order of header file inclusions and dependencies

Tags: c++, dependencies, header-files

I'm just trying to test splitting code into multiple files.

I have:

```
//testMultiple.cpp

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "testInclude.cpp"

int main(){
    std::cout << "hi";
}
```

and

```
//testInclude.cpp

class testClass{
    public:
        string x;
};
```

This is giving `testInclude.cpp:3:9: error: ‘string’ does not name a type`

I thought since it was including  before it included the testInclude.cpp, string would be defined for use in testInclude.cpp.

Comment: Why are you including a `.cpp` file, instead of linking it with your `testMultiple.cpp`?? That's very unusual, and will break most buildsystems and IDE's.

Comment: Because as far as I know, if you want to split your program into multiple files, you `#include` them

Comment: No, that's wrong. You split them into a header file containing the class declarations, and a `.cpp` file containing the corresponding definitions. Other translation units (`.cpp` files) use `#include` to get the declarations from the header.

Comment: @DavidBandel Maybe you should first read a few question, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945846/what-should-go-into-an-h-file).

Comment: @DavidBandel _"I had no idea it was a useless inclusion and string was actually defined in iostream."_No, you can't rely on this. If you use `std::string` use `#include <string>`.

Comment: Yes that says to put them in .h files. So I changed it to testInclude.h and that didn't fix anything

Comment: Ok I figured out what I was doing wrong. I got it to work with #include <vector> in the header file like you said. So I'd just like to understand why I can't include vector in the main cpp, before I include the header file and the header file have access to vector. Does this mean if I have a bunch of code across a bunch of files, I have to include all my libraries and header files in each one?

Comment: I had this idea, from all the examples and tutorials I went over that std was an iostream thing. I understand what a namespace is better now. I had the naive idea that needing to preface something with std:: without a `using namespace std` meant I was using something defined in iostream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including a **cpp** file, not a **hpp** file. 
Common practice is to include header (h/hpp) files, not implementation (c/cpp) files.

If you only compile `testMultiple.cpp`, this should work. If the compiler is compiling `testInclude.cpp` separately, it will not see the `#include

Try renaming `testInclude.cpp` to `testInclude.hpp` and ensure it is not being compiled.

Here's an example:

```
///// testInclude.h
#include <vector>
class testClass{
    public:
         std::vector<int> x; // vector is in std namespace
};

///// testMultiple.cpp
// #include <vector> - gets this through testInclude.h
#include "testInclude.h"

int main(){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `std::string` instead of `string`.

Comment: That doesn't help me. It still won't use `<string>` which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It's not enough here. He's declaring his class in a cpp, which is compiled. But it fails as string is unknown in the context of this cpp.

Comment: I changed it to hpp and it still fails

Comment: I modified the code in the question. vector is a better example

Comment: Ok thanks. It worked your way. I just had a misunderstanding of where vector gets defined.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
class testClass{
    public:
        std::string x;
};
```

Comment: I already have `#include <string>` See my first file And I'm not trying to use the `<iostream>` string. I'm trying to use the `<string>` string. I simply want to split my code into multiple files.

Comment: @DavidBandel What do you mean _"I'm trying to use the `<string>` string"_? I don't get what you want, the answer is correct. It's the way you try to organize your code that's wrong.

Comment: I am trying to put some code in another file, then include it, so that my code is split across multiple files. That's all.

Comment: Ok thanks. It worked your way. I just had a misunderstanding of where vector gets defined.