# What exactly should I declare in a header file in C++?

Tags: c++, header-files

I have searched almost every website I could, but nobody has been able to answer my question. Basically what I ask, is what exactly should I place in a header file? I know of function declarations, but are variable declarations in a .h file also a thing? I need to know what the "tradition" or the "usual method" is of usage of header files.

**EDIT :** If this helps, I just recently started C++ and my objective with learning this language is an opportunity to get into the industry, mainly gamedev, and I need to know what the proper way of doing stuff is. Hence the question.

Comment: Your book should explain how to use header files.

Comment: If you're just starting, and you want to get into the industry, and you want to do gamedev, stop searching random websites and start learning by properly studying [a proper book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4386278).

Comment: I can find many websites that discuss what goes into header files, including [elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945846/what-should-go-into-an-h-file). Not sure where you looked.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings i understand that the best way to learn is using a book, but i am still in school and it is extremely hectic. although once things become a little easy, i do intend to pick one up. thamks

Comment: @shreksleafgreenpp Like anything, you'll get out what you put in. Nothing worth doing is "easy". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header files conventionally contain declarations of entities that you wish to share between translation units.

That usually means *class definitions*, *type aliases*, and *function declarations*.

A translation unit, very roughly speaking, is "a .cpp file".

So, if you use a function in `a.cpp`, and you also use it in `b.cpp`, a declaration for it needs to be available in both translation units, and the best way to do that is to write it *once* in a header file, then include the header file in both `.cpp` files.

That's it.

While it's possible to declare variables in a header file, it's rare to do so. For starters, you'd want to put `extern` on it to make it *not* a definition (you don't want multiple definitions!). At that point, you have to ask yourself why you're not using a class.