# C++ header and implementation files: what to include?

Tags: c++, header, implementation

There is a .h file and a .cpp file with the same name but different extension.

If I want to use what's in the .cpp file, do I include the .h file or the .cpp file?

Comment: Many dupes including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280033/c-header-files-code-separation

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The simple answer is that you almost always want to include .h files, and compile .cpp files. CPP files are (usually) the true code, and H files are (usually) forward-declarations.

The longer answer is that you may be able to include either, and it might work for you, but both will give slightly different results.

What "include" does is basically copy/paste the file in at that line.  It doesn't matter what the extension is, it will include the contents of the file the same way.

But C++ code is, by convention, usually written this way:

SomeClass.cpp -

```
#include "SomeClass.h"
#include <iostream>

void SomeClass::SomeFunction()
{
  std::cout << "Hello world\n";
}
```

SomeClass.h -

```
class SomeClass
{
  public:
    void SomeFunction();
};
```

If you include either of those, you can use the code from it.  However, if you have multiple files that include the same .cpp file, you may get errors about re-definition.  Header files (.h files) usually contain only forward declarations, and no implementations, so including them in multiple places won't give you errors about re-definition.

If you somehow manage to compile without errors when including .cpp files from other .cpp files, you can still end up with duplicate code.  This happens if you include the same .cpp files in multiple other files.  It's like you wrote the function twice.  This will make your program bigger on disk, take longer to compile, and run a bit slower.

The main caveat is that this implementation/forward declaration convention doesn't hold true for code that uses templates.  Template code will still be handed to you as .h files, but it (usually) is implemented directly in the .h file, and won't have accompanying .cpp files.

Comment: +1 great answer, without any "NEVER". One shall alway use common sense in partitioning the code. And yes, by convention the header file (*.h) must be designed in a way that it can be safely included everywhere without imposing any extra dependencies or side effects (like having "using namespace ...") on the compilation unit where it included to.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say, "include .h files, and compile .cpp files," you mean in addition to including the header (.h) files from your so-called main class, you must also add the implemetation (.cpp) files to the compiler line along with the main class?

Comment: @StockB: Not sure what you mean by "along with the main class", because there is no "main class" in C++, but what you're saying is vaguely correct. Also, different compilers work differently, so I can't say that you can definitely add multiple cpp files to the command line of the compiler you're using. The main distinction is that `.h` files tend to be included, whereas `.cpp` tend to be passed directly to the compiler.

Comment: By "main class" I meant the class with the main() function in it. I'm using GCC and found myself that this does indeed cause the program to compile correctly. I was previously including the .cpp files in my code until my supervisor indicated that practice was discouraged and only .h files should ever be included. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Usually it's better to write in the header file .h

```
#ifndef H_someClass
#define H_someClass

class SomeClass {
public:
    void SomeFunction();
};

#endif
```

so that you won't get errors about re-definition when you need to include the .cpp file in other files.

Answer (score 3):

The .h file usually contains the class declaration and the .cpp file the class definition (implementation). You should include the .h in the .cpp file.

A good rule of thumb is to NEVER include a .cpp file, because the `#include` directive just copies the content of the included file into the including file. You may end with some multiple inclusion / definition and you definitely don't want to do that.

Comment: Not that the OP is asking about this, but you may want to #include source files when defining template code.  You might do this to if you are trying to keep the forward declarations and implementations in separate files, or you are working on solving template related code-bloat.  See: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html