# How to separate a template class in source and header files?

Tags: c++, templates

According to this question: [Separate classes into separate files in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884710/separate-classes-into-separate-files-in-c), we can do:

`a.hpp`:

```
class A
{
    private:
        int value;
    public:
        A(int value);
        int get_value();
};
```

`a.cpp`:

```
A::A(int value)
{
    this->value = value;
}

int A::get_value()
{
    return value;
}
```

But, I have no idea how to do something like that, when the class `A` is template, like:

`a.hpp`:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    private:
        T value;
    public:
        A(T value);
        T get_value();
};
```