# I keep getting this error: expected primary-expression before 'int'

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve this exercise on Exercism website. The exercise is about finding the leap year. I have two files, main one and the header file.

The main one:

```
#include "leap.h"



int main (){

leap::is_leap_year(int year);

}
```

The header file:

```
    #if !defined(LEAP_H)
    #define LEAP_H
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    
    namespace leap {
    bool is_leap_year(int year) {
    bool status=1;
    if (((year%4 == 0)&& (!(year%100==100))) || ((year%100==0)&&(year%400==0))){
    
    return status;
    }
    else{
        status = 0;
       
     return status;
    }
    }
}  

#endif // LEAP_H
```

Whenever I run this code I keep getting this error: expected primary-expression before 'int'

If I removed int from

```
leap::is_leap_year(int year);
```

I will get this error: 'year' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Is there a good reason you're not using `true/false` instead of `1/0` here? `bool status=1;` and `status = 0;` You might also think about marking the function in the header `inline` or declaring it in the header and defining it in a cpp file. If you don't you'll have trouble if you include that header in multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about the differences between [function](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) declaration, definition and call. As for your question what you're doing wrong here is that you're not passing any value to your function which it expects. Instead you're just declaring an int and hence the error. Declare and initialise the value before passing it to the function.

```cpp
int year;  //declare before using it
year = 20;
leap::is_leap_year(year); //passing a value
```

Comment: I did the edits you recommend and I got the following error "multiple definition of `leap::is_leap_year(int)'; "

By the way I was curious of why my post get downvoted? Did I do something wrong? This is my first time posting here and I am not familiar with etiquette.

Comment: @Wadah Maybe you're defining the function multiple times. That's what the error is telling at least. I have rewritten your code in on file [here](https://www.ideone.com/9mp5pI). Also tried by making a separate header file and works fine. Have a look at the code and maybe you can figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: For information on how to ask good questions here so you don't get downvoted see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and guidance. I can see that your code is working on my IDE but when I tried in in Exercism website it throws bunch of errors again  such as ( In function 'void ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0()':
/tmp/leap/leap_test.cpp:10:14: error: 'leap' has not been declared)

I believe these errors are related somehow to the test cases the website is using. My guess is that I should write my code in a certain way so that the website can test it. Anyhow I am still new in my journey and will come back to this problem after few weeks and see if I can figure it out

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will do my best to follow these tips

Comment: @Wadah Coding sites have a set of predefined instructions for writing a solution so general solutions may not work. That website only wants you to implement the function and calling is done automatically. So you only need to declare and define the function but not call it. See my [solution](https://exercism.org/tracks/cpp/exercises/leap/solutions/avm-dev).

Comment: @Wadah Declarations are done in header files(files with .h extension) and definition/implementation is done in separate file(.cpp file). Here are some links to help you understand better about declaration and implementation- [Link1](http://www.cppforschool.com/tutorial/separate-header-and-implementation-files.html) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280033/c-header-files-code-separation/280048#280048)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I do really appreciate it. I almost quit using this site while the issue was really simple. again I appreciate the time and the effort you spent here